# Get JSON and use data in Java for Android Development Project

Tags: java, android, json, sdk

I am new on Android Developing. I am trying to get the JSON form URL and use it like this

```
TextView content = new TextView(this);
content.setText(  --> CONTENT/HELLO WORLD <--   );
```

I have a JSON like this

```
{"content": "hello world"}
```

I already tried `JSONParser, JSONObject` it doesn't work for me. Please can you give me possible solution for this problem

Comment: How are you getting the response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your response is a json, you can retrieve the value like this:

```
String sContent = response.getString("content");
content.setText(sContent);
```

But if your response is a string, do this:

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(response);
String sContent = root.getString("content");
content.setText(sContent);
```

This code should be inside a try...catch